# Cannot create an instance of subclass of AndroidViewModel

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

My ViewModel class is in Java and my Activity class is in Kotlin. I am getting the error

> 09-18 14:01:32.737 14082-14082/com.meme.archcompwordlist
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.meme.archcompwordlist, PID: 14082 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.meme.archcompwordlist/com.meme.archcompwordlist.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class
>   com.meme.archcompwordlist.WordViewModel
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of
>   class com.meme.archcompwordlist.WordViewModel
>       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:207)
>       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134)
>       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102)
>       at com.meme.archcompwordlist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:37)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
>       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:199)
>       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134) 
>       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102) 
>       at com.meme.archcompwordlist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:37) 
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for
>   com.meme.archcompwordlist.room.WordRoomDatabase. WordRoomDatabase_Impl
>   does not exist
>       at android.arch.persistence.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:93)
>       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:630)
>       at com.meme.archcompwordlist.room.WordRoomDatabase.getRoomDatabase(WordRoomDatabase.java:22)
>       at com.meme.archcompwordlist.WordRepository.(WordRepository.java:21)
>       at com.meme.archcompwordlist.WordViewModel.(WordViewModel.java:22)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
>       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:199) 
>       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134) 
>       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102) 
>       at com.meme.archcompwordlist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:37) 
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Here is my AndroidViewModel class

```
public class WordViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private WordRepository repository;

    private LiveData<List<WordEntity>> allWords;

    public WordViewModel(Application application){
        super(application);
        repository = new WordRepository(application);
        allWords = repository.getAllWords();
    }

    public LiveData<List<WordEntity>> getAllWords(){
        return allWords;
    }

    public void insert(WordEntity word){
        repository.insert(word);
    }

    public void deleteAllWords() {
        repository.deleteAllWords();
    }
}
```

And here is my activity class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var wordViewModel:WordViewModel
    private lateinit var newWord:EditText
    private lateinit var recyclerView:RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter:WordAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        adapter= WordAdapter()
        recyclerView= findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.wordList)
        recyclerView.adapter=adapter

        //establish a connection to the current ViewModel
        wordViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WordViewModel::class.java)

        newWord = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.insertWord);
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.submitWord).setOnClickListener {
             fun onClick(v:View?){
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(newWord.getText())){
                    wordViewModel.insert(WordEntity(newWord.getText().toString()))
                }
            }
        }
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.deleteWords).setOnClickListener{
            fun onClick(v:View?){
                wordViewModel.deleteAllWords()
            }
        }


        wordViewModel.getAllWords().observe(this,Observer<List<WordEntity>>(){
            fun onChanged(words:List<WordEntity>){
            adapter.setWords(words)
        }
        })

    }

}
```

Could someone please help me identify what I am doing wrong? I am trying to pick-up Architecture Components after a long time away from Android. I am not entirely clear how to proceed.

Comment: Would you paste the logcat which crash occured? Not just a line of error? Thanks. However I'm suspecting that this might cause the issue: `public WordViewModel(Application application)`

Comment: Posted the whole error.

Comment: The error seems unrelated to ViewModels: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.meme.archcompwordlist.room.WordRoomDatabase. WordRoomDatabase_Impl`

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I was curious why you asked for the whole trace and so look deeper into the scary stuff and found that I needed some gradle dependencies to start: 
    **annotationProcessor  "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$lifecycle_version"** My code is in a better state now

Answer (score 5):

I met the same problem and find resolution from [How to fix 'Cannot create an instance of ViewModel class'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56412140/)

You should pass a `ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory` to `ViewModelProvider` as follow:

```
WordViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this, new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication())).get(WordViewModel.class);
```