# How to fix 'Cannot create an instance of ViewModel class'?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-jetpack

I trying hands on MVVM architecture, I implemented all required classes and methods. While creating an object of ViewModel class in MainActivity, I got this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.prathameshmore.getnotes.viewmodel.NoteViewModel`.

I trying this example from a YouTube tutorial. I did all the implementation correct. I tried on making ViewModel class and constructor public but still, app crashing at runtime.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
    noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Note> notes) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

NoteViewModel.java

```
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private NoteRepository noteRepository;
private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;

public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    noteRepository = new NoteRepository(application);
    allNotes = noteRepository.getAllNotes();
}

public void insert(Note note) {
    noteRepository.insert(note);
}

public void update(Note note) {
    noteRepository.update(note);
}

public void delete(Note note) {
    noteRepository.delete(note);

}

public void deleteAllNotes() {
    noteRepository.deleteAllNotes();
}

public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
    return allNotes;
}

}
```

NoteRepository.java

```
public class NoteRepository {

private NoteDao noteDao;
private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;

public NoteRepository(Application application) {
    NoteDatabase database = NoteDatabase.getInstance(application);
    noteDao = database.noteDao();
    allNotes = noteDao.getAllNotes();
}

public void insert(Note note){
    new InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
}

public void delete(Note note) {
    new DeleteNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
}

public void update(Note note) {
    new UpdateNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
}

public void deleteAllNotes() {
    new DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(noteDao).execute();
}

public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
    return allNotes;
}

private static class InsertNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {

    private NoteDao noteDao;

    private InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao) {
        this.noteDao = noteDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Note...notes) {
        noteDao.insert(notes[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class UpdateNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {

    private NoteDao noteDao;

    private UpdateNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao) {
        this.noteDao = noteDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Note...notes) {
        noteDao.update(notes[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class DeleteNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {

    private NoteDao noteDao;

    private DeleteNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao) {
        this.noteDao = noteDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Note...notes) {
        noteDao.delete(notes[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private NoteDao noteDao;

    private DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao) {
        this.noteDao = noteDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids) {
        noteDao.deleteAllNotes();
        return null;
    }
}


}
```

Log

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.prathameshmore.getnotes, PID: 28833
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.prathameshmore.getnotes/com.prathameshmore.getnotes.views.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class
>   com.prathameshmore.getnotes.viewmodel.NoteViewModel
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.prathameshmore.getnotes.viewmodel.NoteViewModel
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:208)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:135)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:103)
>           at com.prathameshmore.getnotes.views.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6868)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:200)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:135) 
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:103) 
>           at com.prathameshmore.getnotes.views.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6868) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.prathameshmore.getnotes.database.NoteDatabase.
>   NoteDatabase_Impl does not exist
>           at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:94)
>           at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:851)
>           at com.prathameshmore.getnotes.database.NoteDatabase.getInstance(NoteDatabase.java:31)
>           at com.prathameshmore.getnotes.repository.NoteRepository.(NoteRepository.java:20)
>           at com.prathameshmore.getnotes.viewmodel.NoteViewModel.(NoteViewModel.java:21)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:200) 
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:135) 
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:103) 
>           at com.prathameshmore.getnotes.views.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6868) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
>   Application terminated.

Comment: Post the entire stack trace, which probably includes more error.

Comment: Says `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.prathameshmore.getnotes.database.NoteDatabase. NoteDatabase_Impl does not exist`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a factory class for your `ViewModel`.

```
public class MyViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private Application mApplication;
    private String mParam;


    public MyViewModelFactory(Application application, String param) {
        mApplication = application;
        mParam = param;
    }


    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new MyViewModel(mApplication, mParam);
    }
}
```

And when instantiating the view model, you do like this:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MyViewModelFactory(this.getApplication(), "my awesome param")).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Comment: The `AndroidViewModelFactory` that you get by default is enough for an `AndroidViewModel` constructor, you don't need a custom factory for that.

Comment: So I don't need to create `ViewModelFactory` class

Comment: Use Android KTX instead of factory for ViewModel

Answer (score 3):

This would work fine:

1.Go to your build.gradle(Module:app) and add this in the dependencies :

```
`implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"`
```

make sure to have the `def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"` in your dependencies.
So it shoud look like this:

```
dependencies {

    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"  //make sure to have this 

    //Some implementations ...  

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version" // make sure to have this too.

}
```

2.Go to your Activity (in your case it's the `MainActivity`) and put this line:

```
noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(NoteViewModel.class);
```

So your `MainActivity.java` should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(NoteViewModel.class);
    noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Note> notes) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Update, Enjoy coding :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

3.Run your app.

Answer (score 3):

Put this

```
noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(NoteViewModel.class);
```

instead of

```
new ViewModelProvider(this).get(mainActivityViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering to CBS's answer as with 2.3.0-alpha01 update **lifecycle-extensions** artifact is no longer published.

[Lifecycle Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#version_230_2)

Dependencies

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.4"
```

AndroidViewModel Class

```
class TestVM (app : android.app.Application) : AndroidViewModel(app){
    //Code
}
```

In Fragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TestVM::class.java)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I accidently put this in project gradle which prevent or exculded the lifecycle dependencies and viewmodel from the project. Remove it

```
allprojects {
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0"
    exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module: 'lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx'

}
```

}