# Can Not create Instance of ViewModel class

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I am working with MVVM architecture and I don't get it why am I having this error? My other classes have the same structure and they are working perfectly fine. Below i have shared the code for both my Fragment Class and the ViewModel Class along with the error

> Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.beyond.sellandtrack, PID: 5380
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.beyond.sellandtrack.screens.dashboard.DashboardViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:275)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
    at com.beyond.sellandtrack.screens.dashboard.DashboardFragment.onCreateView(DashboardFragment.kt:33)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:809)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
    at com.beyond.sellandtrack.screens.dashboard.DashboardFragment.onCreateView(DashboardFragment.kt:33) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:809) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963) 
 Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at com.beyond.sellandtrack.screens.dashboard.DashboardViewModel.<init>(DashboardViewModel.kt:20)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
    at com.beyond.sellandtrack.screens.dashboard.DashboardFragment.onCreateView(DashboardFragment.kt:33) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:809) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5380 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

> Fragment Class

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentDashboardBinding>(
            inflater,R.layout.fragment_dashboard,container,false
        )

    dashboardViewModel= ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
```

> ViewModel Class

```
class DashboardViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
lateinit var user: User
private var auth : FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
private var repository: Repository = Repository()

init {
    user =  repository.getUserData()!!
}
```

Comment: Please show DashboardViewModel full code

Comment: I just missed the closing bracket of class here, otherwise its the full code, i did not make any functions in viewmodel yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'Cannot create an instance of ViewModel class'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56412140/how-to-fix-cannot-create-an-instance-of-viewmodel-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the getUserData is not null. in init block

```
init {
    user =  repository.getUserData()!! //you are forcefully marking this as non null
}
```

check if the **getUserData()** is returning null here or not. Which is null most probably and that's why it's failing

Comment: yess!! that's what the issue was, Instance is getting created now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try `Koin` to inject and create instance of ViewModel.
Its easy to use and syntax is brief.
https://insert-koin.io/.

```
// Injected by constructor
class MyViewModel(val repo : MyRepository) : ViewModel()

// declared ViewModel using the viewModel keyword
val myModule : Module = module {
  viewModel { MyViewModel(get()) } 
  single { MyRepository() }
}

// Just get it
class MyActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

  // lazy inject MyViewModel
  val myViewModel : MyViewModel by viewModel()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your DashboardViewModel class should extending from ViewModel() not AndroidViewModel()

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
class DashboardViewModel : ViewModel()
```

Comment: Does not make a difference. AndroidViewModel should be working fine as well. I tried viewmodel() tho, its not working either